# Split a large file into smaller files with n line in each file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, subprocess, sh

I need to split a large file into smaller file using bash.
For example, Lets say a large.txt file have 10000 line of text data.
I want to split it into 500 file named as file01, file02, file03,....., file99, file100, ......, file499, file500. Each file contains 20 lines.

I am using following command

`split --additional-suffix=.txt --numeric-suffixes=1 -l 20 large.txt file`

Above command only creating 99 files (file01, file02,.......,file99). There should be 10000/20= 500 files. I don't where its going wrong.

Any lead highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you add the output of `wc -l large.txt` as well as the output of your `split` command with an additional `--verbose` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @oliv for the explanation. Similar command below also work(It names file with four digit , as -a is 4, starting from 0000  )

`split  --additional-suffix=.txt -d -l 20 -a 4 message.txt file`

(Here -d by default start file naming from 0000 . We can use --numeric-suffixes=1 ,to start from 0001 )

Answer (score 3):

You need option `-a` to have the indexes on 3 digits.

```
split --additional-suffix=.txt --numeric-suffixes=1 -l 20 -a 3 large.txt file
```

The default index length is 2 digits which doesn't fit indexes until 500.

As explain in `split --help`:

> -a, --suffix-length=N   generate suffixes of length N (default 2)